# My commented code becomes one line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to not let code blocks become one line? Example:

```
                /*
                 * for (String word : tokens) { if (!StringUtil.hasUppercaseOrNonletter(word)) { filtered.add(word); } }
                 */
```

I don't want to reduce the length of my comment line. For other general comments, I still want to keep the line length.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here

Comment: @JamalH: He's asking about Eclipse's aggressive formatter.

Comment: Oh I get it now

Answer (score 1):

If the comment is code that you want, then you can just use the eclipse toggle comment which is Ctrl + /

That just makes every line a normal comment so the formatting doesn't get messed up. You can just redo the command if you want to uncomment. That's what I do when commenting code

Answer (score 0):

After you write the block, just add `/*` to the line before the block, and `*/` after the block, like this:

```
    /*
    for (String word : tokens) {
        if (!StringUtil.hasUppercaseOrNonletter(word)) {
            filtered.add(word);
        } 
    }
    */
```

This will comment the whole block of code, without changing the formatting. Just write/paste the block first.

Or you can do <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>on a mac(for windows use <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>), which will make the block look like this:

```
//      for (String word : tokens) {
//          if (!StringUtil.hasUppercaseOrNonletter(word)) {
//              filtered.add(word);
//          } 
//      }
```